# Phonegap 403 Forbidden

Tags: ajax, cordova, cross-domain, http-status-code-403

I have to develop an application for Android and iOs. To do this I need to use cross domain ajax requests, as i am using Phonegap for the development.
The problem is the following : when i use the html / css / js code from a browser, even from a smartphone browser, I get my answers correctly from my server. But, when I do the same requests using the same code on my compiled Phonegap Application, I get a 403 Forbidden response, though I have the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' on the server side.

I've been searching for a solution for a while on the internet, but I found no thread talking about that kind of problem.
Does someone have an idea ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I suspect u are using PhoneGap version 2.3.0 or lower . In this case you need to white list 
All external domain access must be white listed in PhoneGap in 2.3.0 or lower versions.  Otherwise PhoneGap blocks them by default. See full details here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide .    In 2.4.0 version of PhoneGap, all domains are whitelisted by default.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately, I'm using Phonegap 2.4.0. Although I've tried the fix given in phonegap documentation, it still doesn't work :/
But after a few research I saw that Android 4.1 had an origin policy bug, though I didn't find any fix yet...
I'm gonna continue my researches. But thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @user2104589 are you find any solutions?

Comment: I finally changed the way I did my requests and used jQuery instead of XMLHttpRequest object, and it worked :) hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Its been long I know but I had similar issue with 403 forbidden response. but on my side it was file permission, changed it to 755 and all good now.